# Find the domain of holomorphicity of the function $f(z) = Log(3z - i)$ and calculate $f'(z)$ there.

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that $Log(z)$ is holomorphic whenever $z$ is in the complement of the non-positive real axis, D. (note: $Log$ is used to denote the standard principal branch).

In order for $f(z)$ to be holomorphic, we must then have $3z - i \in D$. This holds precisely when $z$ is in the complement of $R = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |3z - i| = -|3z - i|\right\}$ . Moreover, by the chain rule, we have $f'(z) = \frac{3}{3z - i}$.

I would appreciate any criticisms/pointing out of mistakes/tips for improving this argument. Moreover how does $R$ look geometrically? Is it simply the non-positive real axis translated by $\frac{1}{3}$ 'up' the imaginary axis?

Comment: Write $z=x+iy$, $x$ and $y$ real numbers and stablish conditions over $x$ and $y$. Since it's the logarithm of a degree 1 polynomial (a rotation plus a translation), its domain is likely to be as you described.